# Create a blob storage container programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement whereby on creation of a company an associated blob storage container is created in my storageaccount with the container name set to the string variable passed in. I have tried the following:

```
public void AddCompanyStorage(string subDomain)
    {
        //get the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());

        //blob client now
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();            

        //the container for this is companystyles
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer("https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/" + subDomain);
    }
```

This however has not created the container as I expected, am I going about this in the wrong manner? Is this possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
    public void AddCompanyStorage(string subDomain)
        {
            //get the storage account.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());

            //blob client now
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();            

            //the container for this is companystyles
           CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(subDomain);

            //Create a new container, if it does not exist
           container.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
```

**Follow the guidline for container names:**

- A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the
  following naming rules: Container names must start with a letter or
  number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-)
  character.
- Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by
  a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container
  names.
- All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
- Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Comment: Cheers had just found this on other post :)

Comment: One minor error in your sample code; the method on CloudBlobContainer is called **CreateIfNotExists** (not Exist). Otherwise thanks, good example.

Answer (score 4):

```
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer("https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/" + subDomain);
```

This just creates an instance of `CloudBlobContainer` object. To create a container in your storage account, you would need to call [`CreateIfNotExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexists%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) or [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.create%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) function on this object.

Try this code instead:

```
public void AddCompanyStorage(string subDomain)
    {
        //get the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());

        //blob client now
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();            

        //the container for this is companystyles
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(subDomain);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

    }
```