# Create blob storage container in c# using fluent API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using the [C# management API of Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-management-libraries-for-net-generally-available-now/) to create my resources in the cloud. I am stuck creating a container in the blob storage. I did create a storage account following [these instructions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-accounts/blob/master/Program.cs):

```
// storageAccount here is a Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent.IStorageAccount instance
var storageAccount = _azure.StorageAccounts
                .Define(name)
                .WithRegion(region)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
                .WithBlobEncryption()
                .WithOnlyHttpsTraffic()
                .WithBlobStorageAccountKind()
                .WithAccessTier(AccessTier.Hot)
                .Create();
```

But I do not know how to go on from there. From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#create-a-container) it seems that I have to retrieve a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount` instance, but the `storageAccount` instance I obtain with the above code lives in the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent`, and I have not found any way to get the `CloudStorageAccount` from there.

Is it possible to create containers directly with the API in the fluent namespace? If not, how do I get the `CloudStorageAccount` instance from my `IStorageAccount` one?

[This answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607446/create-a-blob-storage-container-programmatically) is not helpful because it does use the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` namespace directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to create containers directly with the API in the
>   fluent namespace? If not, how do I get the CloudStorageAccount
>   instance from my IStorageAccount one?

At least as of today, it is not possible. When it comes to managing storage accounts in Azure, there are two REST APIs - [`Storage Resource Provider REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/) and [`Storage Service REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference). Former deals with management of storage account themselves (like creation/updation etc.) while the latter deals with the data in storage account. You can say that the former API deals with control plane and the latter deals with data plan. Creation of a blob container falls under latter category.

`Fluent API` you mentioned is a wrapper over `Storage Resource Provider API` while `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` library is a wrapper over `Storage Service REST API`. You would need to reference this library in your project to create blob containers.

What you could do is get the access key (key 1 or key 2) using the Fluent API. Once you have the key, you will create an instance of `CloudStorageAccount` using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library and create a blob container using that. I know that this is not the answer you're looking for but unfortunately this is the only way as of today.

Comment: Thank you so much [@Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri), it is not the answer I was looking for but it clearly explains why it doesn't work as I expected.  It is  really a pity that you can't create blobs directly using the object returned by the storage account creation, it feels like the natural way to do it. Hope Microsoft improves these APIs in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with Fluent API. Using your `StorageAccount`, you can do:

```cs
storageAccount.Manager.BlobContainers.DefineContainer(containerName)
.WithExistingBlobService(resourceGroupName, storageAccountName)
.WithPublicAccess(PublicAccess.None)
.CreateAsync();
```